M1 Mac: Debugging Fails for golang via vscode
When launching the debugger from VSCode for golang (a launch.json that once worked).
I get the following error message in VSCode via a popup.
Failed to launch: could not launch process: fork/exec /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver: no such file or directory

Trying to launch the debugserver directly I get the following:
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver -D -F -R 127.0.0.1:30000 /path/to/go/file.go
debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1500.0.404.7
 for arm64.
error: failed to launch process /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver: Permission denied
Exiting

The google queries I ran all were for x86 installs of these tools, which isn't my issue.

What do you get when you run xcode-select --install?

@eik ❯ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: Command line tools are already installed. Use "Software Update" in System Settings or the softwareupdate command line interface to install updates

For me, the following was the issue:
launch.json
{
      "name": "CLI: Useful name",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      "program": "cmd/gofile.go",
      "cwd": "/Users/username/github/path/does/not/exist",
      "buildFlags": "-tags=dev",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args": [
        "my:args"
      ]
    }

The path under cwd didn't exist, make sure you cwd points to a dir that exists.
